# Can you use a union range to define an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, union

I'm trying to define a 2-d array using data from 2 separate columns. the code currently defines my array only as the first column (range1), ignoring the second (range2). Is this due to a mistake on my part or can I just not use a unionised (is that the right term?) range to define an array?

```
 Sub define_array()

Dim FTSE100() As Variant

Dim wsh As Worksheet

Dim range1 As Range
Dim range2 As Range
Dim finalrange As Range

Dim a As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer

' define array

Set wsh = Sheet2
wsh.Activate

finalrow = Range("a1").End(xlDown).row

Set range1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(finalrow, 1))
Set range2 = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(finalrow, 5))
Set finalrange = Union(range1, range2)

' FTSE100 = finalrange

' Sheet15.Range("A:B") = FTSE 100

' Original code ended here

ReDim FTSE100(1 To finalrange.Areas.Count)

For a = 1 To finalrange.Areas.Count
FTSE100(a) = finalrange.Areas(a)
Next

With Sheet15.Range("A:B")
For a = 1 To .Columns.Count
.Columns(a).Resize(UBound(FTSE100(a))).Value = FTSE100(a)
Next
End With

End Sub
```

That seems to have done it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it quite this way with a non-contiguous range.

You could do this though:

```
ReDim FTSE100(1 To finalRange.Areas.Count)

For a = 1 To finalRange.Areas.Count
    FTSE100(a) = finalRange.Areas(a)
Next
```

You would have to do a similar `For ... Next` loop to write the values

```
With Sheet15.Range("A:B")
For a = 1 To .Columns.Count
    .Columns(a).Resize(UBound(FTSE100(a))).Value = FTSE100(a)
Next
End With
```

But now it dawns on me that your problem is really more simple than this: you just want to copy values from a uninionizd range to another worksheet.  That's easy and doesn't require an intermediary array variable `FTSE100`.

```
Set range1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(finalrow, 1))
Set range2 = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(finalrow, 5))

Sheet15.Range("A:A") = range1
Sheet15.Range("B:B") = range2
```

Comment: I tried it, and it's not throwing an error but it also doesn't seem to be defining an array either. Now, when I run it, nothing is appearing in sheet 15 and attempts to msgbox values from the array are throwing errors.

Comment: Then you didn't try it right. Please revise your Q to show the code you *currently* have attempted to implement and I'll see what seems to be the problem :)

Comment: You also won't be able to write out to Sheet15 that way.

Comment: Let me revise my answer, because I just realized that what you think your problem is, is not actually your problem.

Comment: How would I write this out to a sheet to check it's being defined correctly?

Comment: See revision. I would personally go with the second option. It's totally unnecessary to use an array in this instance. Your actual use case may require it, though, so in that case use option 1.

Comment: You wouldn't write it to the sheet to see if it's being defined correctly, you'd use a breakpoint and examine the variable in the Locals window of the VBE :)

Comment: All of that last comment was new to me, this is much easier than what I was doing for debugging before, thanks for your help.

Comment: See here for some tips on debugging :) http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx  I didn't know about these for a loooong time. Once you start to debug this way, you'll learn so much faster! Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for me to PM you? I'm just starting out with VBA in a job where I'm going to need it a lot, I read your profile, can you recommend some good resources/books/courses/etc. for teaching myself VBA in  a comprehensive manner?

Comment: Pearson's site is good: http://cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx, I've learned a ton here on SO just by browsing Q&A from other people, the Object Model Reference is also a lifesaver sometimes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: But otherwise I'm self-taught through trial-and-error, and google :)  There is a book by Jay Walkenbach (I think he also has a blog/website) that is also highly recommended but I have not read it.